# CoronaSDK Two scenes on the screen at the same time

Tags: android, ios, lua, coronasdk

I'm using the Corona SDK and I'm still fairly new to it. I am using the Storyboard api to navigate scenes. I have a main page with a button on it. The button listener uses gotoScene to open another scene that has a tab bar. When I run the app, the button works, but the new scene is created on top of the first scene. The problem is that both scenes are being displayed simultaneously. I tried implementing destroyScene with a simple print("destroyScene called") to see if it was even being called and it wasn't. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I feel like I'm missing some fundamental functionality of the storyboard api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Destroy Scene is only called when you run out of memory.

You need to use exitScene to turn off the visibility of the things instead (also remove inside exitScene any event listener, so you don't trigger it by accident, and add those back on enterScene).

Answer (score 1):

you can find all the answers to your questions about Storyboard API in Corona SDK by referring this  [sample-code](https://github.com/ansca/Storyboard-Sample)